# Asp.Net MVC Razor BootStrap Input Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootswatch

**Currently I have an Input form like this:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VenueID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueID)
        </div>
```

**I want to convert it to using the following bootstrap code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputVenueID" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Venue ID</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVenueID" placeholder="VenueID">
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I do this, so that I can still use the same `Razor` syntax of `HTML.LabelFor` / `EditorFor` / `ValidationMessage` etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueID, new { @class = "sr-only", @for = "txtVenueID" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VenueID, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ID:" , @id="txtVenueID" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueID)
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add CSS classes using Razor syntax as shown below.  All you need to do is specify the Bootstrap class(es) you want to use.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VenueID, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueID)
</div>
```

Comment: I thing the textbox also need to come inside .col-lg-10 class