# How can I write Bootstrap css class for TextboxFor when it's under @foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Please help me how can I write Bootstrap css class for `@TextboxFor` when its under `@foreach` loop

```
foreach (MasterTable item in Model._ListMasterTable)
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x._ListMasterTable, new { Value = item.Master_Name });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353824/asp-net-mvc-razor-bootstrap-input-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC Razor BootStrap Input Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353824/asp-net-mvc-razor-bootstrap-input-form)

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
foreach (MasterTable item in Model._ListMasterTable)
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x._ListMasterTable, new { Value = item.Master_Name, @class = "YOUR BOOTSTRAP CLASS HERE"});
}
```